# Cannot find LaTeX Error

Tags: polyglossia

I get an error and I don't know the reason:

```
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)                      
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)                           
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)                      
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/breqn.sty                                
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/flexisym.sty                             
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/cmbase.sym)                              
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathstyle.sty)))                         
(d:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf          

! LaTeX Error: \do undefined.                                                     

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.                          
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                                             
 ...                                                                              

l.6 }                                                                             

?
```

I think this is the following line which generate it:

```
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setotherlanguage{english}
```

But why?

**UPDATE**
Small example:
File1.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{breqn}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Consolas}
```

File2.tex

```
\input File1.tex
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE2**

Here is [the log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/74215916/EssentiaIntegrationTechniques.log)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The code you provided runs fine. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Note that you need to use `\input{File1.tex}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Undefined control sequence.

Comment: @Werner Does not matter\

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX? `fontspec` will only work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @matth  yes I use Xelatex

Comment: @user14416 Welcome to TeX.SX! You now have enough reputation to upvote David Carlisle's answer; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote. Upvoting (and accepting an/the answer if you find it helpful) is the proper way to say thank you. To upvote the answer, click the upward pointing arrow to the left of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the weird file structure?

Anyway, there seems to be some strange interaction between the packages, in particular I had to move `amsthm` this loads without error with `xelatex File2`

File1.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{breqn}
\def\do{}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Consolas}
\def\do{}
```

Comment: Hi David. There is an incompatibility between Polyglossia and amsthm, in the sense that Polyglossia, via fontspec, includes fixltx2e, that makes `\[` protected (amongst others).  However amsthm tries to redefine it (around line 400), and fails.  I have contacted the AMS in order to try and resolve this; however for the moment the easiest workaround, as you’ve found out yourself, is to load amsthm before Polyglossia, fontspec, or any other package that loads fixltx2e, for that matter.

Comment: Oh, and you don’t need to include fontspec at all in your document, Polyglossia does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For mysterious reasons, `flexysym.sty`, which is loaded by `breqn.sty`, does

```
\edef\do{%
  \noexpand\AtEndOfPackage{%
    \catcode\number`\"=\number\catcode`\"
    \relax
  }%
}
\do \let\do\relax
```

In the LaTeX kernel, `\do` is used in many places as a scratch control sequence, but *never* it is said `\let\do\relax`. Unfortunately, `polyglossia` relies on this fact and `gloss-english.ldf` uses `\renewcommand*\do[1]{...}`.

This should be regarded as a bug both in `breqn` and in `polyglossia`.

Saying `\def\do{}` after `\usepackage{breqn}` cures the problem.

---

A better way to do what `flexysym.sty` does is

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\AtEndOfPackage{%
    \catcode\number`\"=\number\catcode`\"
    \relax
  }%
}\x
```

without using `\do` which is usually defined (with various meanings) as a macro with an argument.

Comment: Hi Enrico.  To address the Polyglossia end, I’m going to use `\def` instead of `\newcommand`; can you see any side effect to that change?

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer There should never be a problem in doing `\def\do{...}` instead of `\renewcommand*{\do}{...}`. I'd even say it's the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I wanted to hear ;-)  I have to say it seemed odd to me that François chose `\renewcommand` instead of `\def`, and I always meant to look into it.