# adding \chapter in KOMA scrbook generates a "! LaTeX Error: \do undefined."

Tags: macros, sectioning, errors, chapters, koma-script

**Context:** This question is a follow-up of [Handling _ (underscores) in a macro's comma-separated list of arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367411/64454). In this question I create the macro `\codecitep` that takes a comma-separated list as argument, and prints these keys generating `hyperref` links.

**Problem:** My MWE works great, however, I did not succeed in implementing it in my real document. I indeed get the following error:

> `! LaTeX Error: \do undefined.`

I have tracked down the cause, which is... the `\chapter` command: 
`\codecitep` commands positioned *before* the first `\chapter` compile well, but those *after* don't.

**Solution:** (Yep, the solution comes before the question!) As suggesting in [Cannot find LaTeX Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79341/64454), reseting `\do` definition after the error-causing command makes compilation work.

However, adding `\def\do{}` after each `\chapter` command is way to dirty, and I don't think redefining/patching KOMA's `\chapter` command with `\def\do{}` as suffix is a sustainable solution.

**Question:** What makes `\chapter` change `\do`'s definition, and how to avoid it impacts my own `\codecitep` macro?

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newcommand{\codecitep}[1]{% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454
        [%
        \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem{\hyperref[code:##1]{##1}}}% How to process each item
        \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
        ]%
    }   
\begin{document}

    \section{Body before chapter}
        A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
        Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.

\chapter{Chapter title}
%\def\do{}% <----- uncomment to make the error disappear
    \section{Body after chapter}
        A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
        Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.
        \lipsum[1-2]

    \section{Appendix}
        \lipsum[3]

        \subsection{key1}
        \label{code:key1}
        \label{code:a_123}
        \lipsum[4]

        \subsection{key2}
        \label{code:key2}
        \label{code:bb_456}
        \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\def\do` in your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `tocbasic.sty` used by `scrbook` does

```
\let\do\relax
```

as part of `\doforeachtocfile`, which is executed by `\chapter`. This means you cannot do `\renewcommand\do{...}`, because `\do` is undefined according to LaTeX.

Indeed, if I remove `\let\do\relax` from the two internal macros doing it, the problem disappears.

The `\renewcommand{\do}{...}` issue has appeared in other situations. The best, in my opinion, is to use your own list processor.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\codecitep}[1]{% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454
  [%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
  \forcsvlist\codecitepitem{#1}% Process list
  ]%
}
\newcommand{\codecitepitem}[1]{%
  \nextitem
  \hyperref[code:#1]{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Body before chapter}

A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by 
dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Body after chapter}

A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by 
dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Appendix}

\lipsum[3]

\subsection{key1}

\label{code:key1}
\label{code:a_123}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{key2}
\label{code:key2}
\label{code:bb_456}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing this vs. using `\def` instead of `\renewcommand` (apart from avoiding TeX constructs)?

Comment: @AlanMunn It's much cleaner, besides avoiding the issue. `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

`\do` is used in many low level latex constructs, just looking through `latex.ltx` there is

```
 \global\let\do\noexpand
```

in `\begin{document}`

```
  \let\do\@makeother
```

and

```
\let\do\do@noligs
```

in `verbatim` and `\verb`

```
\let\do\@makeother
```

in `filecontents`

I didn't trace exactly what is resetting it in your use case but basically it should only ever be used for a local definition immediately before the `\do` separated list is executed.